# How to make Cypress execute an API script on a page?

Tags: typescript, automated-tests, cypress, end-to-end

I’m currently trying to convert my Protractor code into Cypress code. Some of my Protractor code involve making the webpage execute an API script for instance:

```
import { browser } from “protractor”; // this is the import I used

browser.executeScript(‘arguments[0].click()’;, this.closeButton); // this is for button clicking

browser.executeScript(‘localStorage.setItem(“example-boolean”, “false”)’); // this is for setting a value to false
```

Is there a Cypress equivalent for these lines of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some inspiration:

```
import "cypress-localstorage-commands";

cy.get('#yourCloseBtnId').click();  // Clicking on the element with an ID #yourCloseBtnId

cy.setLocalStorage("example-boolean", false);  // Setting an item in the local storage
```